# My GET request works fine in POSTMAN and Curl, but not in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I make my get request with POSTMAN or Curl, it works just fine and I get the expected response. I just set type to GET, insert my URL and insert a key named token/email and set it to a token/email I get from another service.
But when I try to call the same service in code like this:

```
   function getAll() {
        const myHeaders = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'token': 'MY TOKEN',
            'email': 'MY EMAIL'
        });


        return fetch('https://apitul', {
            headers: myHeaders,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.json();
            } else {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.debug(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

I get 401 error. I also found out that the server is not receiving the token in the request header. Any ideas how I can fix this? Cheers.

Comment: Error code `401` means _Unauthorized_. Are you sure you provided the correct authentication?

Comment: Hello @code, I sent the same parameters via curl or postman and the return is 200 (my curl: $ curl -H "token: MYTOKEN" -H "email: MYEMAIL" https://APIuRL

Comment: Have you confirmed that the headers are indeed sent with the correct values from JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I even generated the code by postman and it gave the same error ..this is code for javascript fetch: var myHeaders = new Headers(); myHeaders.append("token", "mytoken"); myHeaders.append("email", "myemail"); myHeaders.append("Cookie", "CVid=9injvuffqn6gj3824uh87st595"); var requestOptions = { method: 'GET', headers: myHeaders, redirect: 'follow' }; fetch("api_url", requestOptions) .then(response => response.text())

Comment: @r31sr4r Well, if you look at the curl command you provided, you'll see `token: MYTOKEN`. You need to supply a token in your request in your JavaScript or else you'll get an unauthorized error.

Comment: Using the code genereted by postman i have myHeaders.append("token", "mytoken"). However, checking the header in firefox, I only have the Access-Control-Request-Headers header: email,token, without the values. Do you have any idea why javascript is not able to set the token and email?

Answer (score 3):

To send your token in header use this: 'Authorization': 'Bearer yourToken'

Comment: In this API a had to pass the token on header with a key 'token' ....

Answer (score 1):

[image: Try to generate code using Postman, lets see if it helps. See attached.]

Try to generate code using Postman, let's see if it helps. See attached.

Comment: I generate code e retrive this: curl --location --request GET 'api_url' \
--header 'token: mytoken' \
--header 'email: mymail \
--header 'Cookie: CVid=9injvuffqn6gj3824uh87st595'   .... in curl i recive the json response ... but in javascript i had  Status401
Unauthorized
VersionHTTP/2
Transferred437 B (0 B size)
Referrer Policyno-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: this is code for javascript fetch:             var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("token", "mytoken");
            myHeaders.append("email", "myemail");
            myHeaders.append("Cookie", "CVid=9injvuffqn6gj3824uh87st595");

            var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: 'follow'
            };

            fetch("api_url", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => console.log(result))

Comment: Check if the token is still valid. @r31sr4r

Comment: apparently the token is still valid. I made the call directly through firefox and edited the header passing the parameters and it worked, however through javascript it still doesn't work. I verified that on the console the error is now: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api_url. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)